# Chef Server Error During startup

Tags: chef-infra

I have a standalone chef-server installation. When I start the chef service and check status, all services appear to be running. But, I can't access the web page. It times out. When I review chef-server tail opscode-erchef during start up, I see this error: Could not start the network driver: econrefused.

Any ideas what would be causing this problem? The DB is local to the server so I don't think RabbitMQ is having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out IT enabled the firewall on Linux. Once we fixed that, everything started working.